# License utilisation in Office 365

Tags: azure, powershell

All.
Now we have about 250 PowerBi Pro Licenses, these licenses assigned to our users. And I'd like to now which of this users actually use this software, and which users don't use this Software and just wasting our money. Other words, I need some report showing software usage. And I'd like to do some automation of this process, therefore  powershell cmdlets would be preferable.
Any ideas? I want to at least understand the direction

Comment: Have you checked out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-user-accounts-and-licenses-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide) yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the usage metrics of power Bi

[image]

- Visit the https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/ &
- Sign in & navigate  https://app.powerbi.com/home?noSignUpCheck=1

Click on the **Setting ----> Admin Portal**

Click on the usage metrics :

[image]

Update :

You could also use the Unified Audit logs in order to track the entries
Url https://protection.office.com/unifiedauditlog

[image]

Comment: The above is with regards to power bi utilisation

Comment: Can you please help me with understanding  on your query ? Because my understanding was on your requirement was get the overall usage of the PowerBI by the users.

Comment: Oh okay.. the admin portal has the usage report of all the services where as the above usage report is only specific to power bi services. I'm glad you found the solution :)

Comment: Thanks for you response, but that's not it. I need report, that can say to me "this guy launch PowerBi  (app or web) yesterdsay, and this guy has never launched an app in the last 3 monthso  "... something like that

Comment: Sure, understand - I have updated my answer which covers many activities that you can track and export. Hope it helps you little better